# RenderItems is not defined no-undef inside return

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Hello Guys am new in reactjs and Iam trying to get response data object to be able to display on the webapp for the users to see instead of them inspecting the page and going to network/console to see the file upload error response of name= 'title' so I decided to use the function below to be able to give me the data response and I keep on getting this error **'renderItems is not defined'**  no-undef
Heres the sample code:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import axios from 'axios'
import { Card,} from "shards-react";

class Uploaddatastore extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      UploadNotification: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    let notificationComponent = this;
    axios.get("http://127.0.0:8000/uploads/file_upload/")
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data);

        notificationComponent.setState({
          UploadNotification: response.data.items
        });

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
render() {
      if (this.state.UploadNotification.length) {
        let renderItems = this.state.UploadNotification.map(function(item, i) {
          return <li key={i}>{item.title}</li>
        });
      }
    return (
     <div>
       <span className="text-danger"> {renderItems} </span>
     </div>
    );
  }
};
export default Uploaddatastore;
```

Comment: `let` is block scoped. Move that statement outside the `if`. (In fact you don't appear to need the `if` at all.)

Comment: Hey would also appreciate if you could help make the functionality to be able to present the console response on the page for the user is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You scoped the `renderItems` variable wrong. It was limited to the `if` block. Declare it before the `if` instead:

```js
render() {
    let renderItems;
    if (this.state.UploadNotification.length) {
      renderItems = this.state.UploadNotification.map(function(item, i) {
          return <li key={i}>{item.title}</li>
      });
    }
    return (
     <div>
       <span className="text-danger"> {renderItems} </span>
     </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Christian Fritz it worked thanks although I would like if could help me to fetch the object from the network/console and present it on the webbApp page for the user is it possible?